# Swap the two middle bytes of a word using 4 ARM instructions

Tags: algorithm, assembly, arm

The task is to write code in arm assembler using no more than 4 instructions that swaps the two middle bytes in a given 32-bit word.
For example if the word is `0xAABBCCDD` the result should be `0xAACCBBDD`.
You may use at most 4 arm instructions from the set `AND`, `ORR`, `EOR` and shifts and rotates. You have the word in `r0` register. As a hint they gave following identity `A XOR(A XOR B)=B`.

Comment: I have no idea how to solve this.This was one of the problems on exam. I need much more instructions than 4 :) .

Comment: stackoverflow tries to stay away from homework... You can share your shot, then people might give hints.

Comment: 4? It's easily done in 3 with one scratch register: `ubfx`, `rev16`, `bfi`. Unless, of course, there's crucial information missing from the question, like ARMv7 instructions being off-limits...

Comment: Not a homework just an exam problem.I think interesting one.I didn't found anything like this on web.If this is not allowed on stackoverflow i can delete it ...

Comment: You can improve it... xor swap is generally this one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm

Comment: You can use all available registers and you don't have to save their content.I think we should use only and orr eor and shift instructions to solve this.@Notlikethat if you have solution please add it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hint tells you to create `BB XOR CC` then apply that to `BB` and `CC`. It's an example of the well known `XOR` swap. Something like this:

```
EOR R1, R0, R0, LSR #8 @ R1 = AA BB^AA CC^BB DD^CC
AND R1, R1, #0xff00    @ R1 = 00 00 CC^BB 00
EOR R0, R0, R1         @ R0 = AA BB BB DD
EOR R0, R0, R1, LSL #8 @ R0 = AA CC BB DD
```

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow and sorry my english is not so good.I didn't also know that somebody else can edit my question but thaks any way...

Comment: No problem. I just tried to make it more clear. In general, if you don't agree with an edit, you can roll it back, or further improve it.

Comment: No it's perfect this way - i could make it just less understandable :) Thanks again for your clever solution of the problem.